# get post response using curl and send it laravel api

Tags: laravel, curl

i am new to curl and i started using it, so i have a situation where i have to post using curl to a url and get json response back, everything works fine upto this. So what i wanted to do is have this json response send to a laravel api which in turn parses out and saves to database. this is curl script i use

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Basic Sjg2eFZzdVFkOVFUMTlScEd0==" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
--cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sample.com/fullchain.pem \
--key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sample.com/privkey.pem \
https://connect.innovative.com/auth/token
```

i am not sure if curl can save the response directly to mysql and also how can i setup a scheduling the above script to run every 2 hours in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out by creating bash script and storing it to variable and then subsequent post request to api, also did a crob job and it worked like charm